Setting up express with typescript. No overload matches this call
I was trying to set up a new express server with typescript and I keep getting the following error
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response) => express.Response<any, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>) => Response<...>' is missing the following properties from type 'Application<Record<string, any>>': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 63 more.

I have a routes folder with an index.ts file inside
import express, {Request, Response} from "express";

const v1Router = express.Router();

v1Router.get("/ping", (req : Request, res: Response)=>{
    return res.json({
        msg:"hello"
    });
});

export default v1Router;

I keep getting the error on this line v1Router.get("/ping", (req : Request, res: Response)=>{.
Error Image
I have tried looking everywhere but I couldn't find any solution.
Found this post Typescript no overload matches this call but it didn't solve my issue either.
I also don't wanna use any type.


EDIT
I figured out what the problem was. The issue is with the latest @types/express version. I downgraded to 4.17.21 and it started working fine.

I had a similar issue, I just removed the word return, and it got fixed!
v1Router.get("/ping", (req : Request, res: Response)=>{
res.json({
msg:"hello"
});
return;
});
This should fix it.

removing return worked for me
